# Why I can't access google compute engine with external Ip address on my browser

Tags: jsp, tomcat7, google-compute-engine

I get google compute engine Ubuntu VM and set up tomcat as the server on my VM.
But now I can't visit the external IP address on my browser.
VM instance is seemed not issue.

The route that I did are below:
1st. In Google cloud console, I enabled compute engine, API and billing.
2nd. I made Ubuntu VM instance and enabled http.
3rd. I installed MySQL and Tomcat7 on my VM.

In this status, I tried to visite with external IP address on my browser, but I couldn't.

However, I can access and upload project files to Google Compute VM with external IP address using Filezilla.
In my think, there would be some problems I missed.
If there is someone who know the way to solve, please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

I post this answer for the developers who would have same problem.
At the first, I don't know the solution, but now I can say "I know.".
The solution is simple.

1. In Google Cloud Console, search by keyword "cloud launcher".
2. In Cloud launcher, search by key word "tomcat".

Then 2 items are shown.

Please don't select apache tomcat. It would be possible on other servers, on google cloud it is not necessary.
Please select the other.
Then config page will be shown.
In this you can config as you want.
Next click the ok button.
After making VM, please visit browser with external IP address.
Then you can see Tomcat sample page which start with "It Works".
That is all.
As you can see, all are easy.
Thank you.
"All are difficult before you know, but all are simple after you know."

Comment: This is a very incoherent answer.